# .HTACCESS - Redirect All Parameter URLS (news.asp/id?=1) to same page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

Hi I have many URL's from an old site like below:

`news_article.asp?id=51`

I want to send ALL urls no matter what the ID value to `/news/`

I have tried to the below but I get `/news/?id=51`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=51$
RewriteRule ^news_article.php /news? [NC,R,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as the very first rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=\d+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^news_article\.php$ /news/? [NC,R=302,L]
```